# Tfs tries to merge wrong changeset

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I have 2 changesets in the same file as below.

[image]
[image]

When I select the last changeset only which is 41183 and try to merge between branches, conflict occurs. However, it fetches changeset 41182 instead of 41183. The result should be 2 instead of 1. Why does TFS merge gets the previous changeset?

Enviroment: Visual Studio 2017, Tfs 2017/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems tfs default merge tool is buggy.When I test the same situation with a different merge/compare tool (KDiff3) true output is produced.